# How to handle data synchronisation between 2 Spring apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for the optimal way to handle the following scenario, preferably  some implementation that's already been made for something like this.

There are two Systems (Springboot Webapps) that are supposed to communicate which each other through a Rest-gateway. Transfers shall be handled with Json over HTTP.

1st System is the Project part, 2nd System is the Persons part and they both implement their own persistent sql-database. Both systems depend on each others data and it cannot be expected that both systems are online at all times.

What would be the best way to achieve that both systems data is always up 2 date? Is there any plugin you could recommend to handle the synchronization process which also implements scenarios like one system shutting down while sending or the other way round?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't expect both systems to be online at all times, and you don't want any downtime when one of them is down, I think that the best way to do it is to share a common database. This has some problems of its own and you should think if it's worth, maybe you would be better having two completely independent services which rely on each other and being ready to replicate one of them if it's needed.

Comment: Sharing a common database is not an option unfortunately. Im looking to find a way to handle the synchronization process correctly.

Comment: Are you totally sure that you need to synchronize data between those services? Usually you let each service manage its own domain's data.

Comment: Well what would be your suggestion regarding the architecture? I cant think of a different idea to achieve that both systems data stay as up 2 date as possible.

Comment: Each service holds its own data (Project service holds projects data, Persons service holds persons data). Every time a service needs data from the other service's domain (Persons service needs to know about a project, for example) they call each other using REST APIs, just like you have it working right now.

You should implement retry policies so, when a service is down, the other service will make new attempts to retrieve data until it is back up again.

Comment: Remember that in a microservice architecture, you can have mutiple replicas of the same service up at the same time, so if one goes down nothing bad happens to your whole system.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I thought of too and now i'm looking for the best-practise for this.

Comment: I'm sure there must be some plugin that would handle this situation the optimal way. Sure now we could implement everything by hand but usually it's always a good idea to use an existing plugin or implementation where they already thought of most eventualities.